# Why put 2 in (test_sums == 2).mean()

Tags: numpy

simulate 1 million tests of three fair coin flips

```
tests = np.random.randint(2, size=(int(1e6), 3))
```

sums of all tests

```
test_sums = tests.sum(axis=1)
```

proportion of tests that produced exactly one head

```
(test_sums == 2).mean()
```

Comment: `test_sums == 2` returns array of `boolean` which can also be viewed as 1s (true) and 0s (false). Taking a mean of it will give you a ratio of `(number of 2s) / (number of all the values in test_sums)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if heads is represented by `0` then any test containing only one heads will contain one `0` and two `1`, thus their sum will be exactly `2`

more descriptive way of writing the code would be to check every occurrences of head

```
heads = tests == 0
```

then sum the occurrences per test

```
heads_per_test = heads.sum(axis= 1)
```

and see where total occurrences are exactly 1

```
(heads_per_test == 1).mean()
```